# dictfetchall() doesn't give me results to my query

Tags: python, odoo

I'm working on an odoo framework and I have a SQL query to execute within a function.
The problem comes here is when I run the query separately in a SQL console I could see the data coming in.
But when I execute the same with the cursor and the method dictfetchall() I see 0 records to all my columns with key and value.
code as below:

```
def func(self,cr,uid,data):
    
    # some operation happening here
    dbc_query = """SELECT count(*) as no_of_records, id, values 
                FROM Billing_table 
                WHERE ("id"" != '123')"""
    
    self._cr.execute(dbc_query)
    charges = self._cr.dictfetchall()
    
    print(charges)
    # RESULTS ALL DICTIONARY KEYS AS ZERO VALUES.
```

Comment: what odoo version? Also, the query seems off to  ("id"" != '123'), id is not usually a string , if there is no grouping then there is no counting. Tell us what you want to achieve.

Comment: its odoo 13 version. I mentioned a sample query randomly. In real we used %s for values of the column in where clause and replaced the %s with other variables. for now please consider the where clause as ```id = 123``` and group by values. Let me know why such things happens and is it the issue with the query? when same works in sql console